# PyMySQL is not working as a alternate MySQLdb module for Python 3.4

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-3.x, pip

I'm trying to install a Python 3 alternative to python-mysql. I tried with the recommended PyMySQL. But the same error persists when trying to migrate my Django project.

**Traceback:**

```
File "/home/my_user_name/Dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 27, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

**Versions:**

- Django==1.8.7
- Mezzanine==4.0.1
- PyMySQL==0.6.7
- Ubuntu==14.04
- MySQL==5.5.46
- Created database with `DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci`
- Created a **cnf** file with the database information.

**This is my Django settings:**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'read_default_file': '/home/my_user_name/my.cnf',
        },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [recommended library](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers) for MySQL with Python 3 is mysqlclient.

Comment: @mbadawi23 thanks, fixed

Answer (score 4):

To get pass this I just created this in my manage.py file:

```
try:
    import pymysql
    pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
except ImportError:
    pass
```

This should replace MySQLdb module with PyMySQL.